# Android - Steering with orientation sensor

Tags: android

I am writing a simple 2d game similar to breakout or pong, where you move a bar along the bottom of the screen by tipping the phone left and right.

I am trying to use the Orientation sensor to achieve this movement however i've run into some issues.

After printing out the orientation sensor's values for a while I decided rotation in the Z axis gave me what I wanted, If I hold the screen horizontal and perpendicular to the floor (x: 0, y: 0, z: 90) rotation in Z left and right takes away from 90. So the value 90-z is fine for usage as an "amount of steering" value.

However this perpendicular to the floor position is not very natural to play with, people are much more likely to hold the phone at about 45 degrees in the Z axis, at which point all these values I have been using mess up completely, steering goes weird, people are unhappy..

I guess what I really need is to detect rotation in some z-axis even though the XY plane the phone is in is constantly changing. Is there some clever way to do this with Maths?

EDIT: Just found the OrientationEventListener - Exactly what I needed!